# How to change the Add another item button text for a multivalued field?

Tags: 8

I have tried with this in template_preprocess_input

```
function mymodule_preprocess_input(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if (!empty($element['#name']) && $element['#name'] == 'myfield') {
      $variables['element']['#attributes']['value'] = t('Add another period');
      $variables['element']['#value'] = t('Add another period');
  }
}
```

But this is not working. Is there any other method?

Comment: Did you try a `hook_form_alter`?